# How to fetch specific data from MySQL database to my PHP table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to fetch data from MySQL database to my table in .php file. In every row of my table I want to display title, text and attachment($name) that user can download.
The problem is when I display that, I get all attachments from database shown in list in every table row in my .php file. 
So I want only to display only one attachment per row, from database, that have same ID as title and text of database table row.

This is my database table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`size` int(11) NOT NULL,
`content` longblob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  )
```

My code:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sqlget="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
$sqldata= mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die ('error');
echo"<table>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata,
MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo"<b><font color='#DF01A5'> Title: ".$row['title']."</font></b>";
echo "<br/>";
echo $row['text'];
echo "<br/>";
echo "<b><font color='#DF01A5'>Attachment: </font>";
?>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass') or die(mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('database', $con);
$query = "SELECT  id, name FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
{
echo "Database is empty <br>";
} 
else
{
while(list($id, $name) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<a href="download.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($id);?>"
><?php echo urlencode($name);?></a> <br>
<?php 
}
}
mysql_close();
echo"</table";
?>
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Your code seems to be already doing all what you described.

Comment: You don't have any closing </td> and </tr> tags. Could be the start of your problem. Otherwise, the PHP looks correct, but could use some updating.

Comment: @Kacey This is only part of my code so I didnt copy that, but I have that tags. :)

Comment: Its simple add ` WHERE title = text` to your query string. Check the answer below.

Comment: For me it looks like this. `title` is the `headline` and `text` the  `description`. Or am I wrong? If I am right, the title will never be equal to the description!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use only one while loop

```
$sqlget="SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY timestamp DESC";
$sqldata= mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die ('error');
echo"<table>";
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   echo "<tr><td>";
   echo"<b><font color='#DF01A5'> Title: ".$row['title']."</font></b>";
   echo "<br/>";
   echo $row['text'];
   echo "<br/>";
   echo "<b><font color='#DF01A5'>Attachment: </font>";
   echo "<a href=\"download.php?id=".$row['id']."\">".$row['name']."</a><br />\n";
   ...
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your two tables are related on the ID alone:

```
$sql = $db_conn->query("SELECT t1.title, t1.text, t2.ID AS AID, t2.name FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID ORDER BY t1.timestamp");

echo '<table><thead><tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th>Attachment</th></tr></thead>';
while($row = $sql->fetch_array())
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['text'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="download.php?id=' . urlencode($row['AID']) . '">' . $row['name'] . '</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Not tested, but start with this.

Comment: Thanks, but I have all data in one table. Maybe I should make two separate tables as you suggested.

Comment: @strellson If it's all in one table then why do you have two separate SQL statements to pull the info? Can you edit your question, and add the layout of your table?

Answer (score 2):

We'll need a sample output from this table.  I'm still not sure how those attachments are being stored.  In the meantime, this PHP function should return only one row: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Edit: unnecessary comment.

Answer (score 1):

For your particular condition, this will help help:

```
$sqlget = "SELECT `title`, `text`, `name` FROM `table` WHERE `title` = `text`";
```

Enjoy...

Comment: On the same table ? And what about `id` ? and `title` never == `text`

Comment: @moskito-x  Yes, question asked for the records that have same `text` and`title`.

Comment: @KishorSubedi Thanks, but moskito-x solved. My qusetion asks for the records where `title` and `text` have same `ID`.

Comment: @Kishor : rowcount == 0 . So useless.

Comment: @strellson : `title` and `text` must necessarily have the same id, because all belong to the same data record. That means not that `title` and `text` have the same content.